# Alguém me da uma ajuda? Basic JavaScript: Testing Objects for Properties

Tags: javascript

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Quase deu certo mas gostaria de saber o que falta no código, algo a mais a ser acrescentado?**

```
    function checkObj(obj, checkProp) {
  // Only change code below this line
var myObj = {
gift: "pony",
pet: "kitten",
bed: "sleigh",
city: "Seattle"
};
if (checkObj = myObj.hasOwnProperty) {
  return myObj[checkProp]
} else{
  return "Not Found";
}
  // Only change code above this line
}





    function checkObj(obj, checkProp) {
      // Only change code below this line
    var myObj = {
    gift: "pony",
    pet: "kitten",
    bed: "sleigh",
    city: "Seattle"
    };
    if (checkObj = myObj.hasOwnProperty) {
      return myObj[checkProp]
    } else{
      return "Not Found";
    }
      // Only change code above this line
    }
```

Comment: O código que você apresentou funciona perfeitamente. Talvez haja mais código que você não tenha mostrado e está gerando este erro.

Comment: @JeanExtreme002 quais outros códigos vc usaria? Pois estou testando inúmeras opções aqui mas nenhuma funciona

Comment: Como assim quais outros códigos eu usaria ? O que eu quis dizer para você é que **somente** esse trecho que código que você colocou na pergunta não gera erro.

Comment: com este código quase funcionou: function checkObj(obj, checkProp) {
  // Only change code below this line
var myObj = {
gift: "pony",
pet: "kitten",
bed: "sleigh",
city: "Seattle"
};
if (checkObj = myObj.hasOwnProperty) {
  return myObj[checkProp]
} else{
  return "Not Found";
}
  // Only change code above this line
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O que o exercício deste [site](https://www.freecodecamp.org/learn/javascript-algorithms-and-data-structures/basic-javascript/testing-objects-for-properties) pede é apenas para criar uma função chamada `checkObj` que recebe dois parâmetros (`objeto` e `propriedade`) e retorna o valor da propriedade caso ela exista. Caso a propriedade não exista, a função deverá retornar `"Not Found"`.

O seu problema foi que você criou apenas um parâmetro para `checkObj()` e executou a sua função quando não era para executar. Ao clicar no botão **"Run the Tests"**, o próprio site executa a sua função passando alguns objetos de teste para verificar se a função funciona.

A solução então é apenas criar a função da forma abaixo e mais nada:

```
function checkObj(obj, prop) {

    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
        return obj[prop];

    } else {
        return "Not Found";
    }
}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado ajudou muito aqui, vlw cara.